# How to convert Double dict from file and use it

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have double dict which i want read using json, but i don't really know how. Im running Python 3

```
{ "www.svetaine.lt":{ "true": "111.111.222.11" }}
{ "www.svetaine2.lt":{ "true": "111.111.222.11" }}
```

I know only how to make simple `dict`

```
def openfile():
    data = []
    d={}
    with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            data.append(json.loads(line))
        for item in data:
            d.update(item)
        f.close()
        return d
```

So I would like to improve my code by using double dict.
P.S Could you also mention how I could mention refer to it after reading like

```
for ele in d:
    getname="www.svetaine.lt"
    getstatus="true"
    getip= "111.111.222.11"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import json

def openfile():
    d={}
    with open('s.json', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line_ = json.loads(line)
            name = line_.keys()[0]
            status = line_[name].keys()[0]
            ip = line_[name][status]
            d[name] = {'name':name, 'status':status, 'ip':ip}
        f.close()
        return d

data = openfile()

# print whole dict
for ele in data:
   print ele, data[ele]

# retrieving info w.r.t name 
print data['www.svetaine.lt']
```

Comment: Hi, after running this i get errror at Line:" name = line_.keys()[0]"  that dict_keys obj does not support indexing

Comment: what's your python version?

Comment: latest, not developed version

Comment: apparently I have python 2.7, and its running fine.

Comment: do you know how to remake it to p3 ?

Comment: @Sande I guess your are running python version 3.5, if yes then change line:

`name = list(line_.keys())[0]`

`status = list(line_[name].keys())[0]`